# Local testing Apache Beam with SqlTransform in Python SDK. I receive an error: "'Execution of [%s] not implemented in runner %s.'

Tags: python, sql, sdk, apache-beam, transformation

I am getting an error when using SqlTransform on my local Apache Beam instance. Here is a simple test:

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    pc = (p | beam.Create([
        FruitRecipe("pie", "strawberry", 3, 1.5),
        FruitRecipe("muffin", "blueberry", 2, 2.),
        ])
        | beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(recipe = x[0],  # str
                                 fruit = x[1],    # str
                                 quantity = x[2], # int
                                 unit_cost = x[3], # float
                                 is_berry = x[1].endswith('berry')))) # bool
    pc | SqlTransform(" SELECT * FROM PCOLLECTION WHERE quantity > 1")
```

> 

### The error:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
11                                      is_berry = x[1].endswith('berry')))) # bool
12
---> 13     pc | SqlTransform(" SELECT * FROM PCOLLECTION WHERE quantity > 1") #| beam.Map(print)

```
~/PROJECTS/Apache_Beam/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py in __or__(self, ptransform)
    139 
    140   def __or__(self, ptransform):
--> 141     return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
    142 
    143 

~/PROJECTS/Apache_Beam/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    689         transform.type_check_inputs(pvalueish)
    690 
--> 691       pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
    692 
    693       if type_options is not None and type_options.pipeline_type_check:

~/PROJECTS/Apache_Beam/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply(self, transform, input, options)
    196       m = getattr(self, 'apply_%s' % cls.__name__, None)
    197       if m:
--> 198         return m(transform, input, options)
    199     raise NotImplementedError(
    200         'Execution of [%s] not implemented in runner %s.' % (transform, self))

~PROJECTS/Apache_Beam/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options)
    226   def apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options):
    227     # The base case of apply is to call the transform's expand.
--> 228     return transform.expand(input)
    229 
    230   def run_transform(self,

~/PROJECTS/Apache_Beam/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py in expand(self, pvalueish)
    316       response = service.Expand(request)
    317       if response.error:
--> 318         raise RuntimeError(response.error)
    319       self._expanded_components = response.components
    320       if any(env.dependencies

RuntimeError: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered unsupported logical type URN: beam:logical:pythonsdk_any:v1
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents.getPCollection(RehydratedComponents.java:139)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.lambda$expand$0(ExpansionService.java:422)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1321)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet.lambda$entryConsumer$0(Collections.java:1577)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1602)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:417)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:491)
    at org.apache.beam.model.expansion.v1.ExpansionServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ExpansionServiceGrpc.java:232)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:172)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:331)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:817)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered unsupported logical type URN: beam:logical:pythonsdk_any:v1
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents.getCoder(RehydratedComponents.java:168)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PCollectionTranslation.fromProto(PCollectionTranslation.java:51)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents$3.load(RehydratedComponents.java:108)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents$3.load(RehydratedComponents.java:98)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered unsupported logical type URN: beam:logical:pythonsdk_any:v1
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.SchemaTranslation.fieldTypeFromProtoWithoutNullable(SchemaTranslation.java:316)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.SchemaTranslation.fieldTypeFromProto(SchemaTranslation.java:232)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.SchemaTranslation.fieldFromProto(SchemaTranslation.java:226)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.SchemaTranslation.schemaFromProto(SchemaTranslation.java:212)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslators$8.fromComponents(CoderTranslators.java:169)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslators$8.fromComponents(CoderTranslators.java:151)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslation.fromKnownCoder(CoderTranslation.java:170)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.CoderTranslation.fromProto(CoderTranslation.java:145)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents$2.load(RehydratedComponents.java:87)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.RehydratedComponents$2.load(RehydratedComponents.java:82)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    ... 38 more

 <
```

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** you *should* be able to get around this if you add casts around each field in your `beam.Row` call based on the types you expect, for example:

```
        | beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(recipe = str(x[0]),
                                 fruit = str(x[1]),
                                 quantity = int(x[2]),
                                 unit_cost = float(x[3]),
                                 is_berry = bool(x[1].endswith('berry')))))
```

#### Detailed Explanation

The error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered unsupported logical type URN: beam:logical:pythonsdk_any:v1` indicates that Beam python was unable to determine the type of one of the fields in the PCollection you're passing to SqlTransform. Usually this isn't a big deal, Beam Python just uses a fallback (called `beam:logical:pythonsdk_any:v1`), to encode values for any such field with Python serialization (i.e. pickle). This works fine because downstream Python transforms are perfectly capable of reading that pickle encoded data. There may be some performance implications, but it won't break your pipeline.

However, in the case of `SqlTransform`, under the hood we actually use the implementation from the [Java SDK](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/SqlTransform.html), which has no knowledge of Python serialization. So when it encounters `beam:logical:pythonsdk_any:v1` it gives up.

The solution I suggested above, adding casts around each value, makes sure that Beam python will infer a *specific* type for each field that we can encode in a portable way.

I filed [BEAM-11690](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11690) for this problem. We should raise a more helpful error message in this situation. Thank you for raising the issue!

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I changed accordingly and now the error changed to: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker'

Comment: Hm are you using the DirectRunner? I think you will need to install docker (e.g. for Ubuntu, https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) to run a pipeline that uses SqlTransform

Comment: Yes, this is what I did and it is working now.

Comment: Hi @TheNeuralBit. What do I need to install on docker? I am trying to use sql transform in apache beam using direct runner, but got 'ValueError: Unsupported signal: 2'. I saw your youtube videos saying about Universal Local runner (ULR). How do I install that? Isnt possible in Direct Runner? Thanks in advance